# Opening BBC XML file in Python using urllub2 and lxml gives me 406 error

Tags: python, xml, url, urllib2

I am extremely new to XML and have what I hope is a simple question. I am trying to open an [XML file](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/ion/schedule/date/2014-09-10/masterbrand/bbc_radio_four/) at a location given to me by the BBC. If I click on the link using Firefox sure enough I get a page of XML.

But using Python 2.7.6 under Ubuntu 14.04 if I attempt the following fragment of code

```
import urllib2

xmldoc="http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/ion/schedule/date/2014-09-10/masterbrand/bbc_radio_four/"

u = urllib2.urlopen(xmldoc)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/metatron/Projects/R4/tp.py", line 7, in <module>
    u = urllib2.urlopen(xmldoc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable
```

I've never come across a 406 error before. I would note that the URI I have ben given by the BBC differs from others which usually end `.../something.xml`.

What am I doing wrong? Specifically why can Firefox open the file but not Python? IS there some sort of default xml file which would be loaded (analogous to `index.html`)

Similarly if I do a `root=lxml.etree.parse(xmldoc)` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/metatron/Projects/R4/tp.py", line 8, in <module>
    root=lxml.etree.parse(xmldoc)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3239, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:69955)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1748, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102066)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1774, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102\330)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1678, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101365)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1110, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etr\
ee.c:96817)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lx\
ml.etree.c:91275)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92461)
  File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91722)
IOError: Error reading file 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/ion/schedule/date/2014-09-10/masterb\
rand/bbc_radio_four/': failed to load HTTP resource
```

Comment: I should add if I choose a different XML file e.g. http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/mondial/mondial-3.0.xml the code fragments both work OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some info on HTTP 406 response code [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html), but basically, the BBC server is sensitive to the `Accept` HTTP header which is not automatically set by `urllib2.urlopen()`.

Firefox will set this header to accept most anything - in mine it sets Accept to:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

but `Accept: application/xml` would seem sufficient in this case.

You can set the header like this:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/ion/schedule/date/2014-09-10/masterbrand/bbc_radio_four/',
                          headers={'Accept': 'application/xml'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

>>> print response.getcode()
200
>>> print response.read()[:100]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<ion xmlns="http://bbc.co.uk/2008/iplayer/ion">\n  <blocklist>
```

I recommend that you look at using the [requests module](http://python-requests.org) - it simplifies this to a one-liner:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/ion/schedule/date/2014-09-10/masterbrand/bbc_radio_four/',
                        headers={'Accept': 'application/xml'})
```